# Ng-Click not working on mobile devices. How to change to ngTouch

Tags: angularjs

I have a website which uses angular.js.  The ng-click is working fine on laptop/desktop but not on mobile devices.  From my research, I learned that i need to use ngTouch and I undertand that.  My problem is that I am not a programmer and does not know how to do it.

I am hoping that there is someone who can help me or provide me with the right step or code.  this is my code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MessageBoardCtrl">
  <div class="span6">    
    <div class="row-fluid item" ng-repeat="item in items" ui-animate>
        <div class="span2"><img src="../images/post.png" width="48px" height="48px"/></div>
            <div class=" well well-small">                                        
                <p>{{item.message}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>   

   <div class="span6">
      <div class='well'>                
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMessage()">Share</button>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script src="../templates/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../templates/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../templates/js/angular-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../templates/js/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="../templates/js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function MessageBoardCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.message = '';
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.lastTime = 0;

        $scope.refreshMessages = function() {
            $http.get('../templates/faucet.php/messages?time=' + $scope.lastTime).success(function(data) {
                for(id in data) {
                    item = data[id];
                    $scope.items.unshift(item);
                    if($scope.lastTime<item.time)
                        $scope.lastTime = item.time;
                }
            });
        }

        $scope.sendMessage = function() {
            if(!$scope.message)
                return;
            $http.post('../templates/faucet.php/add_message', {message: $scope.message, email: $scope.email}).success(function() {
                $scope.message = '';
            });
        }

        $scope.periodicRefresh = function() {
            $scope.refreshMessages();
            $timeout($scope.periodicRefresh, 5000, true);
        }

        $scope.refreshMessages();
    }
   </script>
```

Can someone give me a clean code based on the above that will work for ngtouch and instruction as well.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own directive for touch event. Below is an example directive to handle touch events. The directive below only fire the event in case of touch/long touch. scope.isMoved will prevent firing event when user tap on screen and move they finger around.

```
    function directive($timeout) {

    var dir = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            onTouch: '&'
        }
    };
    return dir;

    function link(scope, element) {
        scope.isMoved = false;
        $timeout(function () {
            // user start tap on screen
            element.bind('touchstart', function () {
                scope.isMoved = false;
            });

            element.bind('touchend click', function (evt) {

                if (!scope.isMoved) {
                    scope.onTouch(evt);
                }
            });
            // 
            element.bind('touchmove', function () {
                scope.isMoved = true;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<a on-touch="someFunction()"> Touch</a>
```

Comment: HI Daniel Pham, 

First of all, i want to thank you for your quick response.  I tried to add the function and merge it with the script i have.  I then added the on-touch on my html input but it seems not to work.

    <input type='submit' id='claimbtn' class='form-cf' value='<< Activating in <?php echo $forcewait ?> seconds >>' ng-click="sendMessage()" on-touch="sendMessage()">

Will it be too much if i ask you to modify my code to include the touch function?

Comment: I just created a short example here, http://codepen.io/nguyenpc/pen/zBVQzw
Hope it helps!

Comment: BTW, I have never see any issue like you before, ng-click worked fine with me even on touch devices!